# Narrowing a type based on a string literal in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to type an api response, where resources are returned on a resource name key, i.e. `{ [resourceName]: resources, total: 10 }`. In the following example, how would i type the response object to say that either `apples` or `oranges` are present on the response, depending on what was requested:

```js
interface Response {
    total: number
    apples: Array<object>
    oranges: Array<object>
}

const get = async (fruit: 'apples' | 'oranges') => {
    const data: Response = await fetchFruit(`https://example.com/${fruit}`)
    const count = data.total
    const applesOrOranges = data[fruit].filter(Boolean)
}
```

I *think* I have to use a union type for the different possible responses, but i am not clear how i would be able to narrow the union type, based on the string literal passed into the function:

```js
interface Response {
    total: number
}
interface ApplesResponse extends Response {
    apples: Array<object>
}
interface OrangesResponse extends Response {
    oranges: Array<object>
}
type FruitResponse = ApplesResponse | OrangesResponse

const get = async (fruit: 'apples' | 'oranges') => {
    const data: FruitResponse = await fetchFruit(`https://example.com/${fruit}`)
    const count = data.total
    const applesOrOranges = data[fruit].filter(Boolean)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `fruit` argument of `get` generic (`K`) and resolve the return type dependent on `K`:

```
type FruitResponse = ApplesResponse | OrangesResponse
type FruitResponseKeys = 'apples' | 'oranges' // or extract it from the response types
type FruitResponseByKey<K extends FruitResponseKeys> = Extract<FruitResponse,{ [P in K]: any }>

const get = async <K extends FruitResponseKeys>(fruit: K): Promise<FruitResponseByKey<K>> => {
    // add validation logic for fetched data if you need that
    // we cast it here as any for brevity
    const data: FruitResponseByKey<K> = await fetch(`https://example.com/${fruit}`) as any
    const applesOrOranges = data[fruit].filter(Boolean)
    return { ...data, [fruit]: applesOrOranges }
}

const apples = get("apples") // Promise<ApplesResponse>
const oranges = get("oranges") // Promise<OrangesResponse>
```

`FruitResponseByKey` [extracts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) either `ApplesResponse` or `OrangesResponse` from `FruitResponse` based on a key `K` that is `'apples' | 'oranges'`.

I think, the most useful part is, that the caller gets the proper fruit array depending on the `fruit` key. As `fetch` naturally requires a type assertion, we just use `any` for simplicity in the function body. Also the logic in `get` hasn't any complexity, so this should be a good fit.

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5&ssl=28&ssc=59&pln=20&pc=1#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-ZQ+7iQB3fDUPnwAFwcNQfB821cbD+wPMYuOgHYdK2DkmeBRjhMPEGsG3Y2o22ZjgFnTBsOygAGoZgMDAJgY1tAHHcJQAdLR3JaACQIBXLZCjlW2xJMhs0brwZ6hIQHRq91sk7cAmlLnQyEjVWXAthkbgq4-FmBSKAeCQJcQNbYk70VOlbSyExL3qa9fBmdAmzPGDe25WUACJz1MTD92tOANS1HVgCKGDLimFCBng0x0ODLCvkaPC4AIojtV1K8jilMogA)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the response is wrongly prepared, end point should have one and single structure, if your end point returns `apples` or `oranges` then proper example of modeling the response by BE dev would be:

```
type Response = {
    results: Array<object>
    resultType: 'apple' | 'orange'
}
```

or every object should have own type like:

```
type Fruit = {
  type: 'apple' | 'orange',
  ... other data
}
type Response = {
    results: Array<Fruit>
}
```

> **BTW** - total property also has no sense, you can check the length of the return array.

Or even response could be just `Array<Fruit>`. We really don'y need different keys if we have either apples or oranges

---

Sorry for the complain at the beginning :). Now how to deal with your problem at FE level if response will not change. I would model the type of `fetchFruit` differently in order to say that the result has key provided by argument. Consider such function declaration:

```
type FruitTypes = 'apples' | 'oranges';
// below declaration, you need to provide the implementation
declare function fetchFruit<F extends FruitTypes>(fruit: F): Promise<FruitResponse & Record<F, Array<object>>>;  

const get = async (fruit: FruitTypes) => {
    const data = await fetchFruit(fruit)
    const count = data.total
    const applesOrOranges = data[fruit].filter(Boolean)
}
```

If we say that `fetchFruit` takes an `FruitType` (inside you need to put the url) then we can define return as `FruitResponse & Record<F, Array<object>>` what means that it will return object which for sure has provided key, so if you provide `apples` there will be `apples` key. Ok hope that helps.